# is there any possibility to make call using genymotion . if yes how?

Tags: genymotion

I want know how to make calls from genymotion, if there is any possibility to do so.

I have Ubuntu 16.04. and I've installed genymotion VM virtualbox.

Comment: How do you imagine that would work? You can't make calls through a cellular network if there's no device to access said cellular network. There might be a way to simulate a call to test the emulated application though.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to make calls from any virtual machine. Basically genymotion will provide a virtual device in which you can run android emulator for debugging android apk files. so, it not possible to make a call from genymotion.